# The space is not detected in string

Tags: bash

I use dig to find the IP of a subdomain and assign it to a variable called string. This subdomain has 2 IPs and the IPs are separated by space. I want to say that if there is a space in the string, announce it. I use this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
string=$(dig +short google.com)
echo $string
if [[ "$string" =~ \ |\' ]]    #  slightly more readable: if [[ "$string" =~>
then
   echo "Matches"
else
   echo "No matches"
fi
```

Although there is a space in "string", it says "no matches". I also tried newline character (\n), it wasn't detected as well. What's wrong?

Comment: That's not a space, that's a newline.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I tried new line character by \n, It wasn't detected as well

Comment: Use `$'\n'`, not `\n`, to match a newline.

Comment: First step quote strings: replace `echo $string` with `echo "$string"`

Answer (score 2):

The entries are separated by a newline. You should get used to quote the strings you `echo`.

```sh
case $string in
  *$'\n'*) echo "Matches";;
  *) echo "No matches";;
esac
```

Diagnostic messages should perhaps go to standard error (add a redirect to `>&2`).

<del>Also, the `#` in the shebang line is significant; the first two bytes of the file need to be exactly `#!` in order for this construct to work.</del>

Comment: You could also use `if [[ "$string" = *$'\n'* ]]` (in bash, so be sure to fix the shebang).

Comment: Yeah, I just find `case` less noisy.

Comment: For more information on why the `echo` showed the linefeed as a space, see [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else/29378567)

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better with `host` rather than `dig` as the former provides a shell return code to indicate success or failure:

```sh
if host example.com >/dev/null
then
   echo "Matches"
else
   echo "No matches"
fi
```